# Wijmo dual formatting of one column

Tags: wijmo, msflexgrid

In my Wijmo FlexGrid, in one Dropdown Column having dropdown values (decimal, Percentage).  I need to show percentage symbol if I choose percentage as dropdown values, and decimal `(n2)` if Dropdown value is selected decimal

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the format of the column based on the value using itemFormatter or formatItem event. Here is a fiddle demonstrating similar requirement: http://jsfiddle.net/5Ltfpzst/

```
 grid.itemFormatter = function (panel, r, c, cell) {
        if (panel.cellType === wijmo.grid.CellType.Cell && c == 3) {

            var cellData = panel.getCellData(r, 0);
            if (cellData < 5) {
                panel.columns[c].format = 'n1';
            } else {
                panel.columns[c].format = 'p0';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried in the same way..But in this case I wont be able to edit value. If I double click on the cell,it immediately comes out.

Comment: I think this issue is already being discussed on the following thread:http://wijmo.com/topic/condition-base-formating-on-same-cell/

Comment: Is it possible to apply the same formatting on loaded-rows event?